# Initializing NSStrings with Large, constant html strings

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, nsstring, escaping

I have a large constant html string which I'd like to display on my UIWebView. For some reason, when I try to use the constant string ( with @"LARGE_STRING" ) I get some weird errors, saying I have an unexcpected '@' at the start, that I miss terminating ' " ' characters, that I use undeclared expressions and etc. the thing is - I do escape the string, atleast the ' " ' in it.

What am I missing in here?

Tnx!

Edit: Example:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"&lt;title&gt;&#x05d1;&#x05e1;&#x05d9;&#x05e1;&#x05d9; HTML &#x05dc;&#x05d9;&#x05de;&#x05d5;&#x05d3;&lt;/title&gt; &lt;META http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=iso-8859-8&quot;&gt; &lt;body  bgcolor=&quot;#b5deef&quot;bbackground=&quot;gifs/rekablue.gif&quot;&gt; &lt;center&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;246&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/lim.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;50&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic1.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/hak.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt;  &lt;td width=&quot;230&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/m.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;55&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic2.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/ktiv.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;207&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/ud.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;60&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic2.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/amud.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;163&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/tl.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;55&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic2.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/reshon.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;133&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/ml.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;55&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic3.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/text1.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;  &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;108&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/t.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;35&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic4.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/kish.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;93&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/h.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;35&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic5.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/reshim1.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;70&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/b.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;42&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic6.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/tmunot.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;  &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;40&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/s.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;53&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic7.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/rekaim1.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;10&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/s1.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;45&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic9.htm&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/tfasim.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td width=&quot;8&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td valign=top&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/si.gif&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td width=&quot;30&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;basic8.htm&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/tavlaot.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/td&gt;  &lt;td valign=bottom&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;default.htm&quot; onMouseOver=&quot;self.status='&#x05d7;&#x05d6;&#x05e8;&#x05d4; &#x05dc;&#x05e2;&#x05de;&#x05d5;&#x05d3; &#x05e4;&#x05ea;&#x05d9;&#x05d7;&#x05d4;';return true&quot; onMouseOut=&quot;self.status='';return true&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/shtml11.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href=&quot;bm_guide.htm#html&quot; onMouseOver=&quot;self.status='&#x05d0;&#x05ea;&#x05e8;&#x05d9;&#x05dd; &#x05e0;&#x05d5;&#x05e1;&#x05e4;&#x05d9;&#x05dd;';return true&quot; onMouseOut=&quot;self.status='';return true&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;gifs/shtml10.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt; &lt;/center&gt; &lt;/body&gt;"];
```

Comment: It might help if you posted the code where you're trying to use the string.

Comment: It's quite long and simple, but I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have " characters in the string, then you must escape them:

```
    NSString *myString = @"This string contains \"quotes\". If they are not \"escaped\", that will cause errors".
```

Or, another possibility, you are using #defines like

```
#define LARGE_STRING "This is an extremely large string (well, OK, not so large)"
```

Then you should do

```
#define LARGE_STRING @"This is an extremely large string (well, OK, not so large)"
```

and

```
    NSString *myString = LARGE_STRING;
```

### Edit

Hmmm... your example looks fine. It should compile, if it really contains the HTML-style `&quot;` codes and not hard-coded `"` characters. Just make sure your string (it is really long indeed) is not wrapped with hard linefeeds.

I just tried, and your example compiles fine, in Objective-C (Xcode 4.1). Note that if you try to pass such a string to a C function, it should be converted to a valid C string first.

Comment: You can see the edit above. I have escaped ' " ', as said, but I still get some weird errors.

Comment: What "weird errors" exactly? I just tried your example, and it compiled fine (in Objective-C -- you are using Obj-C, right? Source file should have .m extension)

Comment: I use a different HTML than the one displayed here, with the #define way, and I get like 200 errors, most of them look like : "Stray \327 in program". I also got one "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token", 3 "character constant too long for its type" warnings and two "/Users/Niv/Projects/law.co.il/law.co/HTMLS.h:8:798: warning: missing terminating " character". I'm pretty sure its escaped correctly as well.

Comment: Could you somehow post these constants or make them available online somewhere? If possible, the entire .h file. You may have some bad characters in your file.